# Value cannot be null, paramName: value in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a problem in my linq where clause. Code:

```
public IEnumerable<SearchResult> Search(int? orderId, string customer, string car, int? type, int? status, string sortBy = null)
    {

        var records = Orders.Where(x => (x.Id == orderId || orderId == null) &&
                                        (string.Format("{0} {1}", x.Customer.Name, x.Customer.Surname).Contains(customer) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer)) &&
                                        (string.Format("{0} {1}", x.Car.Mark, x.Car.Model).Contains(car) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(car)) &&
                                        (x.OrderType.Id == type || type == null) &&
                                        (x.OrderStatus.Id == status || status == null));


    }
```

Problem is with orderId, type and status. VS throws exception like in title: value cannot be null, paramName: value. It is strange because these parameters (orderId, type, status) must be null on initialize, when I start searching.

Comment: "must be null on initialize" what do you mean

Comment: What's the type of `Orders` out of curiosity?  Specifically, does it inherit from `IQueryable<>`?  At any rate the error is almost certainly because you're passing a null `customer` or `car` to `.Contains( )`.  You could avoid this by putting the `IsNullOrEmpty()` check first, thus short-cutting the call to `Contains()`.

Comment: I mean, that these parameters doesn't have value when I start filtering, because then I want to have all records.

Comment: I'd suggest you move *all* your `null` checks to the left side of each `||` expression.

Comment: Yes, it works, great thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you pass null to the `String.Contains` method, it throws the "`Value cannot be null. ParamName: Value.`" Exception.
With that being said, I suspect the `customer` or `car` parameter is null.

Comment: One of the the items in the collection could be null, then Contains(null) would be a valid search, that doesn't apply for chars in the string

Answer (score 1):

Contains doesn't like NULL when used in strings, and given that all your parametes are nullable you could separate your query like this:

```
public IEnumerable<SearchResult> Search(int? orderId, string customer, string car, int? type, int? status, string sortBy = null)
{

  var records = Orders;

  if(orderId!=null)
  {
    records=records.Where(x=>x.Id == orderId);
  }

  if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customer))
  {
     records=records.Where(string.Format("{0} {1}", x.Customer.Name, x.Customer.Surname).Contains(customer));
  }

.. and so on

}
```

I think you could have a performance win with this, because asking for each parameter prevents iterating every item asking for its value